# Run a batch file from Inno Setup installer with Administrator privileges

Tags: admin, inno-setup, sqlcmd, elevated-privileges

If made a installer which requires a little script to restore a database and a user. This is a `sqlcmd` script and requires administrator rights.

But I can't get it working in the installer (`runascurrentuser` and/or `PrivilegesRequired=admin`). If I run it manually as administrator, it does work.

Code:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin 

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\DBenUser.cmd"; Components: DbenUser; Flags: runascurrentuser;  StatusMsg: net 2 moveanduser wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
```

I saw somethings about a registry is this the way to go?

Basicly this is little sqlcmd script to restore some db files and create a user.

```
CD\
Net stop MSSQL$NET2
Net stop Net2ClientSvc
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2_Data.MDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2_Data.MDF"
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2_Log.LDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2_Log.LDF"
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2Archive_Data.MDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2Archive_Data.MDF"
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2Archive_Log.LDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2Archive_Log.LDF"
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2Events_Data.MDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2Events_Data.MDF"
MOVE /Y "C:\Program Files\IQ Soft\Net2Events_Log.LDF" "C:\Net2 Access Control\Net2Events_Log.LDF"

Net stop MSSQL$NET2
Net stop Net2ClientSvc
Net start MSSQL$NET2 /m

SQLCMD -S localhost\net2 -Q "CREATE LOGIN b4tmm WITH PASSWORD='b4tmm'"
SQLCMD -S localhost\net2 -Q "SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER 'b4tmm', 'SYSADMIN'" 

net stop  MSSQL$NET2
net start MSSQL$NET2
net start Net2ClientSvc
```

These are all the things the sqlcmd file uses within innosetup (file is called DBenUser.cmd):

```
[Types]    
Name: "Compleet"; Description: "IQ Soft Compleet"                      
Name: "Client"; Description: "IQ Soft Client"

[Components]
Name: "DbenUser"; Description: "DbenUser "; Types: Compleet;

[Files]

Filename: "{app}\DBenUser.cmd"; Components: DbenUser; Flags: runascurrentuser;  StatusMsg: net 2 moveanduser wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
```

[Eddited]

I tested the admin rights by unchecking all my components in innosetup except the sqlcmd script (and running it on a snapshot of vm ware where all the other programs where installed and only needed the script to compleet the installation). If i ran it as the first/only program im my installer it works (so admin rights are ok (also tested this by moving a file to a admin only folder with a cmd script). After that i tested the compleet installation again with all the other components active and it woudn't work. It seems like somehow the installer "loses" its admin rights after all the other components are installed. The cmd gives me the error: **SQLCMD is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file**

```
    SQLCMD -S localhost\net2 -Q "CREATE LOGIN b4tmm WITH PASSWORD='b4tmm'"
    SQLCMD -S localhost\net2 -Q "SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER 'b4tmm', 'SYSADMIN'"
```

(The other components are .net 4,5, Paxton (net2), Sql manager 2012, Sql express 2012, Crystal reports , SQLCMD script in that order)

Anyone has any idea? Im clueless at this point

Additional information

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\IQ-Soft\IQ-Soft.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: IQ_soft;
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\IQ-Soft\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\IQ-Soft\IQ-Soft Setup.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: IQ_Database
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Net4\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; 
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\crystal reports\crystalreports.msi"; DestDir: {tmp}; Components: CrystalReports
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Paxton\SetupPaxton.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Components: Paxton;
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Sdk\RedistOEM.msi"; DestDir: {tmp}; Components: Sdk;
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Sql expr\SQLEXPR.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Components: Sqlexpress;
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Sql expr\SQLMANG.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Components: Sqlman;
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Net2\Net2Databaseschoon\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: Net2DB;
;Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Net2\handleiding.odt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: Handleiding;
Source: "C:\Users\Chris V\Desktop\Net2\DBenUser.cmd"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: DbenUser;

[Run]
Filename:  {tmp}\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe; Parameters: "/q:a /c:""install /l /q""";  StatusMsg: Microsoft Framework 4.5 wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename:   {tmp}\SetupPaxton.exe;Components: Paxton; StatusMsg: Paxton wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
;Filename:  {tmp}\RedistOEM.msi;Components: Sdk; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: Sdk wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filename: {tmp}\SQLMANG.exe;Components: Sqlman; StatusMsg: SQL Manager wordt geinstaleerd even geduld... 
Filename:  {tmp}\SQLEXPR.exe;Components: Sqlexpress; StatusMsg: Sql express wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Filename:  {tmp}\crystalreports.msi;Components: CrystalReports; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated ;  StatusMsg: Crystal reports wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Filename: "{app}\DBenUser.cmd"; Components: DbenUser; Flags: runascurrentuser;  StatusMsg: net 2 moveanduser wordt geinstaleerd even geduld...
```

Comment: this is just the part its about. If anyone needs more info tell me and thx for helping

Comment: *But i cant get it working in the installer*: That's bit vague, what does it do wrong?

Comment: as in it doesnt get the admin rights. If the installer runs it i get acces denied errors and when i manually run it (clicking run as admin) it works

Comment: What commands produce the "access denied" errors?

Comment: Create login and the other one to grand the role. Strange thing is that it does work when manually starting the cmd as admin

Comment: While I have no experience with `sqlcmd`, I find it strange that there's no username/password in the command. How do you authenticate against the DB?

Comment: thats where the parameter (/m) Net start MSSQL$NET2 /m comes in. it will run it in single mode so i can add a user as admin. Basicly all the MOVE files together are  a clean database without a user.

Comment: OK. You should try to write to admin-only folder to verify that the script indeed runs with admin privileges (what I expect). Once you confirm that, I suggest you re-phrase (and re-tag) your question (or post a new one) that's more about the `SQLCMD` use, rather than the Inno Setup.

Comment: Thinking about it it also could be a service that is still running and has to be stopped before i can add a user. Will test this now

Comment: still having issue's updated the question

Comment: If you run the full installer (with all components) and you keep the test command that tries to write to admin-only folder, does it fail or not?

Comment: will check that in a second!

Comment: they both work that way.... (test file to admin only map and db restore with the user)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to create the simplest installer possible that installs a single `.cmd` file and runs it:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
OutputDir=.

[Files]
Source: "test.cmd"; DestDir: {app}

[Run]
FileName: "{app}\test.cmd"; StatusMsg: "running cmd"
```

The `test.cmd` is like:

```
echo a > c:\admintestfile
dir c:\admintestfile
pause
```

I cannot write to `c:\` without Administrator privileges.

As expected, the batch file succeeds, as it is run with Administrator privileges (as long as the installer itself is), as expected:

[image]

---

*So there's probably something else, something specific about the batch file, that causes your problems.*

Answer (score 1):

In the script, you must include full path to the programs.                     E.g.

> %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\NET.exe

then it works.